# Convert CudaNdarraySharedVariable to TensorVariable

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gpu, theano

I'm trying to convert a `pylearn2` GPU model to a CPU compatible version for prediction on a remote server -- how can I convert `CudaNdarraySharedVariable`'s to `TensorVariable`'s to avoid an error calling cuda code on a GPU-less machine?  The experimental theano flag `unpickle_gpu_to_cpu` seems to have left a few `CudaNdarraySharedVariable`'s hanging around (specifically `model.layers[n].transformer._W`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a plain CudaNdarray variable, something like this should work:

'''x = CudaNdarray...    x_new=theano.tensor.TensorVariable(CudaNdarrayType([False] * tensor_dim))
f = theano.function([x_new], x_new)

converted_x = f(x)
'''